Azure ACI cannot pull image from public docker registry (Possible bug)
This used to work, but for some reason Azure ACI now cannot pull image from public dockerhub.
I tried to deploy ACI on two subscriptions (One completely fresh) where i respectively "click opsed" the deployment and did a terraform deployment. (Just to rule out that I had a wierd network configuration in my subscription)
The error that I'm getting is not super elaborate and is the same regardless as to whether i click-ops or use tf:

performing ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 409 (409 Conflict) with error: RegistryErrorResponse: An error response is received from the docker registry 'index.docker.io'. Please retry later.

My terraform (Which used to work) is as follows:
resource "azurerm_container_group" "forwarder" {
  name                = "${var.app_name}-forwarder-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name = var.rg-name
  location            = var.region
  ip_address_type     = "Private"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  subnet_ids          = [var.private-subnet.id]
  restart_policy      = "Always"

  container {
    name                  = "${var.app_name}-forwarder-${var.environment}"
    image                 = "nginx" //Changing image doesn't make a difference
    cpu                   = 0.5
    memory                = 1

    readiness_probe {
      ...
    }

    liveness_probe {
      ...
    }
    ports {
      port     = local.forwarder_local_port
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
  exposed_port {
    port     = local.forwarder_local_port
    protocol = "TCP"
  }


  diagnostics {
    log_analytics {
      ...
    }
  }
}

NSGs are open - Also its worth noting, that trying to deploy a public ACI instance also face the same issue.
Manually pulling the image i.e. docker image pull nginx is no problem.
The region is eu west

The issue is dockerhub has implemented rate limiting. See: https://medium.com/@alaa.barqawi/docker-rate-limit-with-azure-container-instance-and-aks-4449cede66dd
It really doesn't help that the error dockerhub is returning is singularly uninformative of what is really going on. Good work on breaking container deployment...
Suggest: either use a paid dockerhub account, or tag and push the container to your own private container repository (or github container repo etc) See: How to push a docker image to a private repository
Rod

Or use some public alternative like gallery.ecr.aws: https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/14rsai6/dockerhub_alternatives/
